# How to resume Download using this code Java.nio.Channels.ReadableByteChannel in Java

Tags: java, download

I want to resume Downloading in java i am using this code to download file

```
URL website = new URL("http://www.website.com/information.asp");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

modify this code and tell me how to resume.